# Test Class for feilds to check in bulk

Tags: apex

How to write test class for checking record fields in bulk?

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the fields for an object from Schema DescribeSobjectFieldresult. You have to iterate this list on the object/your record like `record1.get(i)` to get the value of `i` field,where the value of `i` will be updated by the loop.